# Acumatica - field type decimal getting cast error

Tags: casting, decimal, customization, acumatica

Customized decimal type field generates error after being published.

I've tried many different syntaxes, if isnull(), etc and for some reason I am not thinking to try the right one.

```
if (tran != null && tran.TranLineNbr != null &&
    arTran != null && arTran.TranType == tran.TranType &&
    arTran.RefNbr == tran.RefNbr && arTran.LineNbr == tran.TranLineNbr)
{    
    decimal? amtOrg = arTran.GetExtension<ARTranExt>().UsrDLYAMTORG;
    tran.GetExtension<GLTranExt>().UsrDLYAMTORG = amtOrg;
}
```

The value on release should go from Ar to Gl.  All the other custom fields work, but not the decimal.

"Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Original Amount.  Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: All most of the time is an issue with the way you defined fields inside DAC extension. Check the type of UsrDLYAMTORG, in the same time the PXDBType of usrDLYAMTORG class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data access class should look similar to

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds extension fields to and modifies attributes in <see cref="ARTran"/>.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ARTranExt : PXCacheExtension<ARTran>
{
    public abstract class usrDLYAMTORG : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Your Field Name")]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.00", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public decimal? UsrDLYAMTORG { get; set; }
}
```

In regards to bringing a custom value from AR to GL on release we have accomplished the same with the following code.

```
public class ARReleaseProcessExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARReleaseProcess>
{
    public delegate GLTran InsertInvoiceDetailsTransactionDel(JournalEntry je, GLTran tran, ARReleaseProcess.GLTranInsertionContext context);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual GLTran InsertInvoiceDetailsTransaction(JournalEntry je, GLTran tran, ARReleaseProcess.GLTranInsertionContext context, InsertInvoiceDetailsTransactionDel del)
    {
        tran.GetExtension<GLTranExt>().UsrDLYAMTORG = context.ARTranRecord.GetExtension<ARTranExt>().UsrDLYAMTORG;

        return del?.Invoke(je, tran, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I started all over again, built everything except this field.  Everything works perfectly including the Release until I put a value into Original Amount field in the Cash Entry screen. It works if I leave Original Amount field blank.  The error occurs on Save.  Once it happens, I can't load the Cash Sale anymore.  I keep getting that same error.: "Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Original Amount. Specified cast is not valid."  The decimal precision and scope was different between the GL Tran and AR Tran and thought once I got them the same it would be fixed, but nope.

Comment: @Rowan Have you confirmed the aspx page has the proper control type and that the database field declarations are correct?

Comment: I don't have access to the SQL Server and suspect the problem is with the table field because, along with the syntax you provided, when i removed that field from DAC and added it back in with a different name, it worked just fine.  Why didn't I think of trying that earlier?  Haha!  I've been working in Acumatica for about two months so half the battle is learning where everything is.  Thank you for your help!  It lead me down a great learning path.